# shell script to create a set of values in a range

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a set of each 3 values within a range using Shell script as shown below.

**Range of values  : 512 -885**

**Columns difference: 12**

**Row increment : 3**

```
512 524 536
515 527 539
518 530 542
......
860 872 884
863 875 513  --> Column 3 Reset
866 878 516
869 881 519
872 884 522
875 513 525  --> Column 2 Reset
878 515 528
881 518 531
884 521 534
513 524 537
....
```

I tried this inline script to generate the above output, but it is not giving the looping again and again.

```
for ((i=512; i<=849; i=i+3));do echo $i `expr $i + 12` `expr $i + 24`;done
```

Comment: Try: `for ((i=512; i<=849; i=i+3));do echo $i $(( i  + 12 )) $(( i  + 24 ));done`

Comment: Not sure how anyone is answering this w/o more info-- is "looping again and again" you trying to say it should be an infinite loop?  You also seem to want each three columns to be treated indivually and reset to 512 when they hit max.  But I'm forced to guess.

Comment: @SaintHax: Yes, It should be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answers SaintHax, Prasanna and ceving. I wrote a similar logic in a basic way as I am a beginner :)

Comment: @PrasadBonthu don't forget to select his answer as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this generates, what you need.

```
#! /bin/bash

lines=1000

start=512
stop=885
colinc=12
rowinc=3
delta=$((stop-start+1))

for ((i = 0; i < lines; i++)); do
  for j in 0 1 2; do
    c[j]=$(( start + (i * rowinc + j * colinc) % delta ))
  done
  echo ${c[@]}
done
```

You need the modulo operation `%` to get the overflow right. I order to get the sequence right you have to sum the ith row increment and the jth column increment. You have to take the remainder of the division by the interval size. And finally you have to add you start offset.

Comment: Your output resets to 513, instead of 512.

Comment: @SaintHax This is required by the example data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your complete requirement, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v start=512 -v end=885 'BEGIN{while(start+24<=end){print start,start+12,start+24;start+=3}}'
```

So providing here start and end variables for starting and ending points, then using BEGIN section here where I am starting a while loop which runs from start variable's value to till end variable's value. So in here this while loop I am printing the start, start+12, start+24 value as per your requirement then incrementing start variable with 3 each iteration of while loop.

**PS:** BEGIN section in awk doesn't require any Input_file to be read.

Comment: I would say this is a clone of what he did and what does not work. If you iterate up to 885 and add 24, you obviously exceed 885.

Comment: @ceving: I have updated my answer now it will print the digits less than 825 only. I will welcome any views or queries on same, thank you for letting me know on same.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing if you want an infinite loop or not, I'll still take a shot at it.

```
declare -i min=$1
declare -i max=$2

for ((i=$min; i<=$max; i+=3)); do
   [ -z $j ] && declare -i j=$((min+12)) || j+=3  # initialize or increment
   [ $j -gt $max ] && j=$min                      # reset if it's over max
   [ -z $k ] && declare -i k=$((min+24)) || k+=3  # initialize or increment
   [ $k -gt $max ] && k=$min                      # reset if it's over max

   echo -e "$i\t$j\t$k"                           # output with tabs
done
```

This terminates when the first column goes over max, but it matches what you've asked for (thus far).  I'm not a fan of hard coding values, so I've moved them out to passed arguments, but you could set min/max outside the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me. Please check if it works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_COLS=3 # number of columns to display

range_min=512
range_max=885

col_diff=12
col_incr=3

max_lines=500 # change it to the maximum number of lines you want to print

#set -x
range_delta=`expr $range_max - $range_min`

for ((line=0; line<max_lines; line++)); do
    value=`expr \( $col_incr \* $line \) % $range_delta + $range_min`
    echo -n $value " "
    for ((col=1; col<MAX_COLS; col++)); do
        value=`expr $value + $col_diff`
        if [ $value -gt $range_max ]; then
            value=`expr $value - $range_max + $range_min - 1`
        fi
        echo -n $value " "
    done
    echo
done
#set +x
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so, below is the code what I did.

```
#!/bin/bash

start=512
end=885
incr=12
col1=$start
col2=$(($col1+$incr))
col3=$(($col2+$incr))
colincr=3
for z in {1..500}
do
    if [ $col1 -gt $end ]
    then
         col1=$(($(($col1 % $end))+$start-1))
    fi
    if [ $col2 -gt $end ]
    then
         col2=$(($(($col2 % $end))+$start-1))
    fi
    if [ $col3 -gt $end ]
    then
         col3=$(($(($col3 % $end))+$start-1))
    fi
    printf '%-4s%-4s%-4s\n' $col1 $col2 $col3
    col1=`expr $col1 + $colincr`
    col2=`expr $col2 + $colincr`
    col3=`expr $col3 + $colincr`

done
```

Comment: No need to nest `$(())` within a `$(())`. And no need to use `expr`, if you use `$(())` already. The command `expr` makes only sense, if you write for very old shells like the original Bourne shell used by Solaris. If you use Bash, you can forget `expr`.